# How to get value outside of asynchronous listener methods

Tags: java, android, listener

I want to get frame counts which can be obtain on listener's overridden methods.

But if I use try to assign value to outer variable I get error.
`error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final`

```java
public void Test5 (String path, Callback cb){
   // 1. initialised count variable
   int count = 0;
   
   decoder.addRenderListener(
     new WebPDecoder.RenderListener(){
       @Override
       public void onStart(){

         // 2. assigning value to count variable
         count = decoder.getFrameCount();
         Log.d(TAG, count); count is non zero

       }
       @Override
       public void onRender(ByteBuffer byebuffer){}
       
       @Override
       public void onEnd(){
         decoder.stop();
       }
     }
   );
   decoder.start();
   
   // 3. accessing the count variable
   Log.d(TAG,"count : "+count);  // still  count is 0
   
   // this won't run as count is 0
   for(int i=0; i < count i++)
       bitmaps.add(decoder.getFrameBitmap(i));
       // and getFrameBitmap(i) is not useful inside above listener overriden methods. This returns bitmap only outside of listener.
 }
```

I tried SharedPreference and it works but I can't use for reliablity and also app crashes.

I also Tried to use custom class. It does not give error But the value is still zero.

```
frameData.setFrameCount(frameCount); // setting in onStart()
frameData.getFrameCount(); // getting out of listener
but still zero because it executes before assignment
```

I wonder how sharedPreference gives non zero value but not this custom class

Comment: make the count variable an upper class field, maybe you need to add sth to check if count is ready.

Comment: You cannot get the count value instantly because the listener is an asnchronous call and it will be called somewhere in the future depending on its events. Where else do you need to use the count?

Comment: @Kozmotronik I just wanted this count to avoid index out bound error while retrieving  the bitmaps using that decoder . I cant get bitmaps in onStart(). it only works outside of listener. But noticed that sharedpref works fine. How it gives values  in synch way. 

Answer (score 2):

To get around the `must be final` you may use a

```
final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

and then

```
count.addAndGet(1);
```

Anyway, line

```
Log.d(TAG,"count : "+count.get());
```

will always return 0, as long it is before `decoder.start()`. Probably you want to put into a Handler and run periodically ?.

Comment: You mean I should keep running loop and check if value set yet or not . I think that will surely work but not reliable way. It seems Risky.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do with the counter outside the context (closure) of `WebPDecoder.RenderListener`. No, looping in the main thread, of course, no. Probably you may run another thread (via a Handler) to log count periodically. But you don't explain your requirement where/when to use count.

Comment: want to get bitmaps using getFrameBitamap(index). But frameCount must be known to avoid the 'indexOutOfBound'. getting bitmaps is not available within overriden methods onStart() , OnEnd() and OnRender(). outside of listeners I can access the bitamaps. So here I need frameCount.

Comment: I have update code snippet in question

Answer (score 1):

Well a more effective way to achieve to control this would be using a LiveData object to keep track of the active counts.

Define the count variable as a `MutableLiveData<Integer>` and update this livedata whenever the `onStart` method called. This may be much faster than writing to and reading from the shared preferences. See the example snippet for an example implementation.

```java
// Define the live data object within a correct scope in your class
MutableLiveData<Integer> mldCount = new MutableLiveData<>(0);

// In the part where you want to control and avoid the index out of bounds observe the count live data
mldCount.observe(<Pass the lifecycle owner here>, count -> {
    // Check the new count here
});

public void Test5 (String path){
   
   decoder.addRenderListener(
     new WebPDecoder.RenderListener(){
       @Override
       public void onStart(){

         // 2. assigning value to count variable
         int count = decoder.getFrameCount();
         // If this callback is called from a background thread use:
         mldCount.postValue(count);
         
         // If it is called in main thread then use:
         mldCount.setValue(count);
         Log.d(TAG, count); count is non zero

       }
       @Override
       public void onRender(ByteBuffer byebuffer){}
       
       @Override
       public void onEnd(){
         decoder.stop();
       }
     }
   );

   // This will not show the valid actual values
   Log.d(TAG,"count : "+mldCount.getValue());  // still  count is 0

   decoder.start();

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got solution but won't accept is as answer beacuse it is not a solution for specified problem in question.

I invoked `decoder.stop()` in override `OnStart()` and then I could access the Bitmaps after stopping. So now no need to get frameCount outside of decoder.